# javascript getting fields from an array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I filled up an array with some objects like this and printing it out with `JSON.stringifty(obj, null, '\t');`

gives me output like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "here's the title"
    },
    {
        "description": "this is a description"
    }
]
```

now I am trying to get the data back from this array with objects inside. Using array.map like this:

```
var title = objArray.map(function(a) {return a.title;});
```

when I do:

```
console.log(title); //the output looks like this
,here's the title,,,
```

If I manually reach into the array like this

```
console.log(results[0]['title']); //the output is well formatted
here's the title
```

why is that and how can I get the map function to not add those additional commas to my returned value?

Comment: `map()` returns an array. If you try to output (e.g. via `console.log()`) an array, it is first implicitly joined, as though you'd done `array.join()`. The commas are a result of that implicit join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because your 2 elements in your array are :

```
{
    "title": "here's the title"
}
```

and

```
{
    "description": "this is a description"
}
```

but they haven't the same properties :
so when you try to display the property `title` in the second element, JS interpretor just return `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It will return a value for everything in the array so you will get these empty values in the resulting array for the objects that do not have a title. You can check for the value of title before returning the value in the map function though. e.g.:

```
if (a.title) return a.title;
```